# Jira Test Center plugin with similar functionality to the Jama Test Center

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, jira, rest

I am working on a new project for which requirements are being managed in Jira. My previous experience is using Jama to manage requirements, test cases and finally test cycles and test runs.

I really like the Jama Test Center in that it lets you create test runs based on test cases. I also like how the Jama REST API allows you to write results to the test runs such that test automation can be achieved.

My question is: is there a Jira plugin that has similar features to the Jama Test Center? So far, I've checked out Zypher and Bamboo.